# How to add own shortcodes in contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

For example i have function

```
function simple_title( ){
return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page-title', 'simple_title' );
```

But i cant add this [page-title] in body message contact form 7 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you have to modify the contact form 7, or check if there is any option to add shortcode into the body message.

What is required to add shortcode into another shortcode is, consider this example:

```
function simple_title($content=null){
    return do_shortcode($content);
}
add_shortcode( 'page-title', 'simple_title' );
```

Now `$content` could be a another shortcode or simply a content like

```
[simple_title][simple_title_2][/simple_title]
```

Now come to the point, the contact form body message should have the code something like `do_shortcode($message)`. Hope your understand.